# Multiple spinners and onItemSelected

Tags: android, events, spinner

I have two spinners that trigger the onItemSelected event. The question is How can I know which one triggered such event ? So far I tried:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{

    Log.d("form","onitemselected");
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.region_spinner:
        Region r = (Region)sregions.getSelectedItem();
        Log.d("form","regionid:" + r.id);
        break;
    case R.id.state_spinner:
        Log.d("form","state id:");
        break;
    }
```

But only the first Log is displayed, so there's no match in the switch.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

use:

```
switch(parent.getId()) {
    ...
}
```

instead is what you need. 
The `view` in your parameter is the actual 'row' (i.e. the clicked child of spinner item), and the parent is the actual 'spinner' that you are after.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with example ?

Comment: Don't know if it's because of a different version but for me it was: `adapterView.getId()`. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

Use below code if you have multiple spinners in one activity and you are using onItemSelected override method

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
         if (parent!!.id == R.id.spinner_1) {
            // first spinner selected
         } else if (parent!!.id == R.id.spinner_2) {
            // second spinner selected
         }
    }
```

either you can use switch case

Answer (score 3):

Spinner is a subclass of AdapterView. The parent object passed into the method is the spinner in which the item was selected.

Answer (score 1):

At first  in onCreate :

```
Spinner cit_for_bus,  bus_number;
cit_for_bus = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cit_for_bus);
bus_number = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bus_number);
cit_for_bus.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
bus_number.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

don't forget to use :
you have to bind/tie spinners to **onItemSelected**

```
cit_for_bus.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
bus_number.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and use implement for class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

outSide of onCreate use this :

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.cit_for_bus) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapterView.getId() + "/ " + adapterView.getCount() + "/" + adapterView.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.bus_number) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapterView.getId() + "/ " + adapterView.getCount() + "/" + adapterView.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import your XML on Kotlin you can use it as so:

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: 
Long) {
when (parent)
    firstSpinner -> {
        // first spinner selection
        }
    secondSpinner -> {
        // second spinner selected
        }
    }
}
```